# issue with dimensions in statsmodels framework

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to use the CanCorr methods from the statsmodels library, but am constantly running into a problem, likely related to the dimensions of the input. When I run the following code:
`c = CanCorr(a,b)`

I get the following error

`ValueError: exog is collinear.`

The shape of `a` is (700, 34) and the shape of `b` is (700, 58), and the values are all integers >= 0. From the statsmodels docs:

``        nobs, k_yvar = self.endog.shape
nobs, k_xvar = self.exog.shape
k = np.min([k_yvar, k_xvar])

```
    x = np.array(self.exog)
    x = x - x.mean(0)
    y = np.array(self.endog)
    y = y - y.mean(0)

    ux, sx, vx = svd(x, 0)
    # vx_ds = vx.T divided by sx
    vx_ds = vx.T
    mask = sx > tolerance
    if mask.sum() < len(mask):
        raise ValueError('exog is collinear.')
```

``

I have changed the dimensions of the inputs by taking different subsets, but am still getting the same error. I have transposed them, which gave me an error for inconsistent matrix sizes. I've been going in circles trying to figure out what the issue is. If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong/what I am required to do, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a constant in exog? Then demeaning would make it into a column of zeros. Check the matrix rank of your x and y.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Josef! I used the add_constant to both matrices with the statsmodels.tools method, which added a columns of 1 to the front of both of them. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error though. The rank is both matrices is 4 (before and after the add_constant). If you have any other suggestions or advice

Comment: I should have specified that I created 2 matrices for testing - both 4x4 matrices with random integers. The above rank refers to these test matrices.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example. It's not clear what you are actually doing. If you demean the variables, then you should not have a constant, and number of rows needs to be much larger than number of column.

Comment: statsmodels CanCorr, demeans the variables before the svd, so the user should drop any constants. It's also not clear that the code in your question is from the CanCorr implementation, and not what you were doing.